# Вывод графиков в GFortran

Tags: график, fortran

Пишу программу на Фортране с использованием компилятора GFortran и 
среды разработки CodeBlocks. 
По результату выполнения программы хотел бы вывести графики. В
интернете много разных библиотек выводящих графики функций но большинство предназначено для компилятора G90.

Есть ли какие-нибудь библиотеки для вывода графиков для компилятора GFortran ? 
Или, возможно, есть какие-либо другие средства визуализации ?
Заранее большое спасибо.

Comment: Скорее всего, вам будет проще всего вывести датасет в каком-нибудь CSV, а его скрутить в график сторонним инструментом, коих полно.

Comment: @Кнопкатык, спасибо за ответ. Получается своих библиотек по визуализации у GFortran нет ?

Comment: По-онятия не имею, но текст он выводить уж точно может, если не в файл, то хотя бы в стандартный вывод, что уже способно решить задачу получения графиков из вычисленных им данных. К тому же, построители графиков общего назначения, скорее всего, будут более продвинутыми. В духе Unix Way: делать одну вещь и делать её хорошо.

Comment: @Кнопкатык, я так подумал, что в плане визуализации GFortran будет весьма примитивным, поэтому придется обращаться к сторонним продуктам. Еще раз большое вам спасибо, за ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Программы на GFortran, насколько мне известно, практически не используются людьми, далёкими от их разработчиков по сфере деятельности, поэтому я обоснованно предполагаю, что вы не делаете "монолитное коробочное решение".

Так что независимо от того, чем вы пользуетесь для вычислений, если оно умеет выводить текстовую информацию в файл (или [в худшем случае] хотя бы в стандартный вывод), то вы можете сформировать файл данных в формате CSV и скормить его практически любой системе построения графиков. CSV очень прост сам по себе, его можно формировать даже без библиотек.

Конкретный построитель порекомендовать не могу, всё зависит от ваших нужд, но если выкинуть ограничение на совместную работу с GFortran, выбор астрономически велик, от пакетов для ТеХ до JavaScript-библиотек интерактивной визуализации в браузере вроде D3.

---

**Disclaimer:** я не утверждаю, что хороших средств визуализации для GFortran нет. *Я не знаю, есть ли они.* Я утверждаю, что независимо от этого строить графики сторонними средствами будет *лучшей* идеей.

Comment: @ Кнопкатык, спасибо большое за подробный ответ. Да, действительно, коробочное решение я не делаю. Фортран мне нужен для математических расчетов (поэтому я его и выбрал). По видимому как вы и писали, лучшим решением здесь будет использование сторонних утилит. Я до этого пользовался математическим пакетом scilab для математических расчетов и программирования в сфере математики и там были встроенные библиотеки для построения графиков.

Comment: Я думал, раз фортран тоже в основном предназначался для математических расчетов, то там наверняка тоже есть библиотеки для построения графиков функций. Оказалось, что все ни так как я думал.

Comment: Вобще то вы изначально думали парвильно. Для фортрана есть огромное количество хороших средств для визуализации. Например pgplot или gnuplotfortran. Глупо было бы думать по другому - большинство вычислительных модулей в мире написано на фортране. И за 50+ лет его использования - ниодин язык близко не приблизился к этому показателю.